# small details in Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem (Real Case)

Tags: functional-analysis

In the real case, of Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem, where $A$ and $B$ are nonempty disjoint convex subsets of $X$ with $A$ open.

Let $a\in A, b\in B$.

Let $C=A-B-a+b$.

I see that $C=\bigcup_{b_0\in B} A-b_0 -a+b$. But why is $C$ open? Is it because it's an union of open sets? But why is each $A-b_0 -a+b$ open?

Also, I don't see why $0 \in C$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ is open then so is $U+x$ for any $x$. This is because $y \to y+x$ is a homeomorhpism. Hence $A-b_0-a+b$ is open. Union of open sets is open.

$0=a-b-a+b \in A-b-a+b \subseteq \bigcup_{b_0 \in B} (A-b_0-a+b)$

Answer (score 0):

First question: Because A is open.
Second question: Because $0 \in A-a$ and $0 \in B-b$